# Where to check the color android.R.color.holo_red_light

Tags: android

I need to know what is the color exactly which is referred by `android.R.color.holo_red_light`. Where to check it? Please advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `your-android-sdk-location\platforms\android-14\data\res` and search for that string in xml files.

Ok, it's

```
<color name="holo_red_light">#ffff4444</color>
```

It's in `\android-sdk\platforms\android-14\data\res\values\colors.xml`